# Android four sided cutted corner

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, material-components-android, material-components

I want to get a drawable shape with four sided cutted corner in android, like this:

[image]

Comment: Is it a button? a textView ?

Comment: textView with background  @GabrieleMariotti

Answer (score 0):

With the Material Components Library you can use the [**`MaterialShapeDrawable`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/MaterialShapeDrawable) to [draw custom shapes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md).

With a **`TextView`** you can do:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/...."
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        ../>
```

Then create a `MaterialShapeDrawable`:

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel = new ShapeAppearanceModel()
        .toBuilder()
        .setAllCorners(new CutCornerTreatment()).setAllCornerSizes(new RelativeCornerSize(0.5f))
        .build();

MaterialShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel);
//Set the stroke
shapeDrawable.setStroke(2.0f,
            ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this,R.color.colorSecondaryDark));
//Apply the shapeDrawable as background in the TextView  
ViewCompat.setBackground(textView,shapeDrawable);
```

[image]

Just a note about `new RelativeCornerSize(0.5f)`: It changed in `1.2.0-beta01`. Before it was `new RelativeCornerSize(50)`.

Comment: is there any way to use through drawable @Gabriele Mariotti